# Inconsistent typography in close reason

Tags: bug, design, close-reasons, wording, spelling

The text for the close reason “unclear what you’re asking” contains four apostrophes: three simplified typewriter apostrophes `U+0027` and one correct typographic apostrophe `U+2019`.

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

The typography should be made uniform.